# Base 64 fwrite using php

Tags: php

I want to use fwrite to post $username in base64 encoded
Here is my current source

```
$fp = fopen("id.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, " $username\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Umm. Consider using [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)?

Comment: ehh `base64_encode($username);`?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something but using the [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) function should work out nicely.

Or does:

```
$fp = fopen("id.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, base64_encode($username) . "\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

not work out for you?

To me it seems that it could.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to store it encoded, use [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/base64_encode).

```
fwrite($fp, base64_encode($username));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a Google search or reading the PHP documentation?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php