# How to encode Base 64 in fput

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Base 64 fwrite using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062136/base-64-fwrite-using-php)

I want to base64encode $username in my code. Which uses fput.

```
fputs($socket, "$username\r\n");
```

Comment: Really not mush different from [what you asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062136/base-64-fwrite-using-php)

Comment: You asked this [question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062136/base-64-fwrite-using-php). base64_encode() works exactly the same everywhere you use it.